# WPF C# Get Visibility of Object

Tags: c#, wpf, visibility

I have a hidden label and text field. I can make it visible but if I try to hide it later it doesn't work, I get a null reference error.

```
if (SMTPAuthValue != "None")
{
    lblSMTPAccount.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    comboSMTPAccount.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
else 
{
    if (lblSMTPAccount.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
    {
        lblSMTPAccount.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        comboSMTPAccount.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

I do not know how to get the visibility property and compare its current state. If you could help me correct the code or succinctly explain why its not working and where I can read more on WPF and C# to better understand why this is not working, I would appreciate that help too.

Comment: Run the code under the debugger and figure out on which line you get the NullReferenceException exactly. Also: the code you show here is just fine, which means there is other code which you are not showing which is setting either SMTPAuthValue, lblSMTPAccount or comboSMTPAccount to null.

Comment: Also, the check for visibility is unnecessary.  If your logic is that "if SMTPAuthValue == 'None', then hide the objects," you can set the visibility to hidden regardless of its current state.

Comment: Use alias for namespace System.Windows.Visibility to avoid repeating.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this is not how WPF is meant to be used. The Visibility should be bound to a value in the ViewModel or to a property of another control. In this case, a binding to SMTPAuthValue using a Converter would be handy.

Comment: @Dave this is the feeling I got but I'm having issues reconciling that the code to make the change lives with the button on the GUI instead of on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

If the `NullReferenceException` is sourced from the code provided then `lblSMTPAccount` or `comboSMTPAccount` must be `null`. Otherwise the exception is from code not included in your question.